# Submitting an update to the App Store from a different project?

Tags: ios, app-store

I have an app in the app store, and I want to release a major update to it. However, I want to re write the application from scratch and then submit it. Am I allowed to create a new Xcode project for the update? What kind of things must stay the same in order for them to accept it as a product update?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, you can do whatever you want on the code side, as long as the Bundle ID (also named Bundle Identifier, and CFBundleIdentifier) stays the same.  This identifier is set in the YourApp-info.plist file:

> com.yourcompany.${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier}

Here `PRODUCT_NAME` is a parameter that is defined in the Build Settings of your Xcode target; this is typically the name of your app.

Note that with any new release you can update the app icon, and even the display name of the app.  But of course you don't want to change these too much, as users may not recognise it as the same app.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you! I'm glad that they've made the process this simple!

Comment: @FedeHenze I did not try (yet), but it's rather fundamental and has been like this for long, I would not expect it to have changed.  You should be able to find it (my answer) in Apple docs.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you can create a new project. Just inside the iTunes Connect app area, where you make the update versions, make sure that you create a new version, and inside your .plist file, make sure that you have the id as the other project.(the one that is usually com.companyName.etcName)

Hope that helps!